# Can't find the table "sales_flat_quote_address"- While Copying an existing Magento site to run locally

Tags: php, mysql, magento

I'm now copying an existing `Magento` site to run locally[`Magento 1.7, Local:WINDOWS+XAMPP3.2.1`] and have finished all the DB import and connection setup, while I try to access the homepage of that local stored website,it keep notifying me about this error:

```
"SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'testing.sales_flat_quote_address' doesn't exist"
```

Also when I try to access the admin panel, it came out this error:

```
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table testing.sales_order_status' doesn't exist
```

I double checked the the database of the existing `MAGENTO` website,and also can't find these two table on that working database.

Anyone has an idea of this?Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, The problem is don't trust the phpMyAdmin export function ,which may give you a faulty Database lack of some tables, you should always use the Cpanel backup function,and I found my self the backup whole site(within myphp folder for the database file) works fine.
But I really don't know why phpMyAdmin has this shortcoming.